# Example usage of TelecomManager and sub classes of TelecomManager for Handling the exact state of Outgoing calls in android

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, phone-state-listener

I am new at Stack Overflow, so please bear with me,

I have been trying since 2-3 days for handling states of outgoing calls. I have found nothing other than PhoneStateListener, but that does not solve my problem, we can not handle the states [Active, Ringing, Dialling, Connected] etc.

After trying more I found that Android has provided something for knowing about the exact states.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Call.html

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/TelecomManager.html

But the thing is I do not have any example that how can I use/implement these classes to in my code to handle states of Outgoing calls.

Please if you know anything about the usage of these classes, help me.

I have tried these things

```
PhoneStateListener listener=new PhoneStateListener(){

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        switch(state){
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            break;
        }
     }

   };
```

but for outgoing calls this ringing state can not be known, as soon as we dial call it fire the OffHook State.

then I found another solution

```
      Method getFgState = null;
      Object cm = null;

      try {
          Class cmDesc = Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.CallManager");
          Method getCM = cmDesc.getMethod("getInstance");
          getFgState = cmDesc.getMethod("getActiveFgCallState");
          cm = getCM.invoke(null);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

       Object state = null;
        try {
               state = getFgState.invoke(cm);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

      if (state.toString().equals("IDLE")) {

      } else if (state.toString().equals("ACTIVE")) {

      }
```

but it always return IDLE state.

I have found something required in above provide two links But I do not know how I can use those classes to find the state of call, where to begin and how to bind listeners with dialler or phone state to know about outgoing call state.

Comment: What did you try? where are you having troubles?

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: Simply I want to know how can I use TelecomManager for finding the Outgoing Call states.

Comment: Hi Ali Hassan Goraya, have you found solution for your question? I have project which has requirements like yours

Comment: No unfortunately, I found nothing on this topic. requirements were changed for my project after that,

Answer (score 0):

The Call API (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Call.html) is only available in Android 6.0 (API level 23), which provides a detailed status of a call. But I doubt there is any phone that's already running 6.0 as of now.

Using TelephonyManager (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) will give you the status of a phone call. For a outgoing call, it has two status: idle and offhook. Offhook means the call is connected.